# sed -e to display only a block of text - can you explain the command?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, edit, ksh

I've managed to build a sed command to achieve what I need with the help of some colleagues but nobody can explain exactly why it works!

Can someone advise please?

My text file is:

```
This is a test

Configuratoin
first test

dn: cn=Configuration
line1 can be anything
line2 can be anything
linex can be anything


end of story

no this is end of story
```

My sed command is:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/dn: cn=Configuration/!d'
```

The output is:

```
dn: cn=Configuration
line1 can be anything
line2 can be anything
linex can be anything
```

I understand that H = Hold (Append newline, then append contents of pattern space, to hold space) and that {} allows multiple commands.

Any guidance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First analysis

First, all expressions given to `sed` through the `-e` option can be grouped into a single script*, so

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/dn: cn=Configuration/!d' my_file
```

is equivalent to

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;};x;/dn: cn=Configuration/!d' my_file
```

Now let's split it to see how it works:

```
sed -e '/./{     # For non-empty lines (containing at least one char): {
            H;   # Happend line to hold space,
            $!d; # and if it is not last line of file, delete it.
                 # Go to next line of input.
           };    # }
        x;       # We reach this point for empty lines and for last line of file
                 # “x” command swaps hold and pattern spaces
        /dn: cn=Configuration/!d  # If pattern space does not contain
                                  # “dn: cn=Configuration”, delete it.
       '
    my_file
```

`!` means: “perform command on lines NOT matching preceding pattern”.

*At least for GNU sed, I don't know for other versions.

## More details

`/./{H;$!d;}`
For all non-empty lines, we save them in `sed` hold space, and delete it from pattern space (except for last line). Then we go to following line of input (the `d` command ends treatment of current line).

`x`
When we meet an empty line, as well as for last line of file (empty or not), we swap hold space (which contains previously saved non-empty lines) and current pattern space. So after swapping, all saved lines are in pattern space, and hold space is empty.

`/dn: cn=Configuration/!d`
Then we look at pattern space (i.e. previously saved lines): does it contain, on any line, the string `dn: cn=Configuration`? If no, delete pattern space (and then both hold and pattern spaces are blank). If yes, do nothing, just print pattern space (i.e. saved lines). Then loop for another line of input.

Putting all of this together, we have: for each stanza containing no empty lines, save it to hold space; on empty line (or at the end of file), get back content from hold space, and search for `dn: cn=Configuration` string inside. If stanza does not contain the string, delete it; else, print it (default behaviour of `sed`).

## Sum up and conclude

So your script prints all stanzas containing the string `dn: cn=Configuration`.
You could remove blank line at top of output and force this string to be on first line of stanza with:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;};x;s/^\n//;/^dn: cn=Configuration/!d' my_file
# Changes:            ^^^^^^^  ^
```

(`s/^\n//` to remove first empty line in pattern space, then `^` to anchor string at beginning of stanza).

Don't hesitate to ask for more details in comments if anything remains unclear.

Comment: Many thanks for the thorough walk through Qeole. Hopefully this will help me take my sed skills to the next level.

Comment: @maddop You're welcome :) To learn more, `info sed` is your friend. There are very nice examples of `sed` usage in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I can not help you with the `sed`, but if the goal is to get the block of data with the `configuration`, you can do:

```
awk -v RS= '/Configuration/' file
dn: cn=Configuration
line1 can be anything
line2 can be anything
linex can be anything
```

By setting the `RS=` to nothing, `awk` works in block of data separated by blank line.
Then the `/Configuration/` gets the block with name `Configuration` within it.